# get All sql history in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to get all `select` and `insert` statement from the beginning in the oracle? I tried,

```
select * from v$sqlarea;
```

but it's giving only today results, but i need all select and insert statement from the beginning where oracle installed or before particular month. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL in the SQL$Area is periodically cleared down based on the least used. Unless you have some other custom logging scheme in place I cannot think of any in-built way of doing this.

Comment: You can use `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` view which stores this information longer than `v$sqlarea` (I'm not sure if using it requires a special license. It could be part of the enterprise or tuning pack license, so please check)

Answer (score 1):

For recent SQL:

```
select * from v$sql
```

For history:

```
select * from dba_hist_sqltext
```